# Connect to QC using Javascript

Tags: javascript, hp-quality-center

Is it possible to connect to QC using Javscript.

I am able to connect to QC using VB Script , but can the same results be achieved using Javascript with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API to perform some actions. Take a look here:

http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Quality-Center-Support-and-News/How-to-access-ALM-data-using-REST-API/td-p/4775940#.UjgmSMZBLz4

Please note that this is not the fastest way to obtain any data, so you nned to consider if you want to call that from JS.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you connect using OTA. Make sure to have the TDConnect.exe plug-in istalled, at least for QC ALM 11:

```
gServer = "http://server-ip/qcbin";
tdc = ActiveXObject("TDApiole80.TDConnection");
tdc.InitConnectionEx(gServer);
tdc.Connect(gDomain, gProject);
```

Note: This will only work on IE on compatibility view mode. Let me know if this helps.